# Changing a value in an Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I've inherited a project at work that uses Azure Cosmos DB. It's completely new to me. In the CosmosDB, we have a bunch of user preferences that are saved. I've discovered a typo in the settings that I need to fix. However, I cannot figure out how to modify the value.

So far I've found the query explorer and I want to run this query:

```
Update c
set c.Setting = REPLACE(c.Setting, 'N*m', 'N-m')
```

but query explorer only supports select, not update.

I tried to use Azure Storage Explorer, but when I try to access the document I get nothing except a modal saying "Hold on! We are still working on this." Seriously Microsoft?

My current thinking is to upload a stored procedure and run that. But I'm not sure where to start. My other thinking is to write a small c# application that iterates through each user document and updates them individually. Something like this:

```
currId = 0;
databaseId = ...;
collectionId = ...;
collectionLink = ...;

while (currId < maxUserId) {

    var response = await client.ReadDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(databaseId, collectionId, currId.ToString()));

    if (response.Resource != null) {
        var upserted = response.Resource;
        upserted.SetPropertyValue("Setting", "N-m");
        response = await client.UpsertDocumentAsync(collectionLink, upserted);
    }

    currId++;
}
```

But boy if that doesn't seem like a dumb idea...

What's the best way to update a single value in a CosmosDB Document?

Comment: If you have a model for this object you can very easily do that with [Cosmonaut](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut) in a small console app. If not then you can create a stored procedure in the data explorer and run that against the collection. Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40684604/how-to-update-a-document-in-documentdb-using-queries

Comment: Unfortunately my predecessor did not have a model.

Comment: You can generate an object based on the document json [here](http://json2csharp.com/), assuming they follow the same structure (you will need to remove the metaproperties like `_ts`, `_etag` etc). If not then check that link i had in the previous comment. Here is another one explaining partial document update https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50244543/how-do-you-update-sub-document-in-cosmos-db